# NUnit RemoteTestRunner will not load app.config

Tags: c#, nunit

I am attempting to run our suite of `NUnit` tests programatically using `RemoteTestRunner`. Some of our tests load configuration information from `app.config` (which VS 2010 turns into `MyTestPackage.dll.config`). I do not seem to be able to get `RemoteTestRunner` to load this config file (the tests run as if there were no config file). I have tried with and without setting `package.ConfigurationFile`, and with/without `package.BasePath`. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    public TestResult runTest(TestDefinition testDefinition)
    {
        NUnit.Core.CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
        RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
        TestPackage package = new TestPackage(@"C:\Test\MyTestPackage.dll");
        package.ConfigurationFile = @"C:\Test\MyTestPackage.dll.config";
        remoteTestRunner.Load(package);
        TestResult testResult = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(), new TestNameFilter(testDefinition.TestName), false, LoggingThreshold.Error);
        NUnit.Util.XmlResultWriter writer = new NUnit.Util.XmlResultWriter(@"C:\Temp\TestResult.xml");
        writer.SaveTestResult(testResult);
        return testResult;
    }
```

Comment: I have identified the issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. When I inspect remoteTestRunner.AssemblyInfo, the assembly path is correct, but the configuration file path is pointing at the config file for the app running the tests instead of the config file for the tests themselves (even though I have specified the correct path in the TestPackage). Has anyone seen this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying or merging the config file into the config for the exe

So if to run this code you call `RunTests.exe` copy that config file to `RunTests.exe.config`

I believe it does ignore the passed in config file, and just uses the app.config for the current context instead... which would be a bug on nunit's end I believe